# Winzip without command line addon

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to untar a file and the software installed on the computer is Winzip, but I've been told that the command line addon isn't compatible with Windows Server 2003, so it isn't installed on it. Is it possible to untar a file with winzip without this addon? And if not would Winrar be the best solution for this problem, rather than Winzip?

Answer (score 0):

We're using [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) on all our Windows machines. This is an open-source alternative to winzip and supports also many other formats like .tar.

If you need to use the command line interface, you may check out [this page showing how to unzip via the command line](http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples).

For example to unzip you can use the `e` (extract) command:

```
7z e archive.zip
```

Comment: The guy who is installing the programs on the server told me that 7-zip doesn't work on Windows Server 2003, although I don't know why it wouldn't.

Comment: The guy is wrong. It even works with Windows 98! Check out the requirements: `7-Zip works in Windows 7 / Vista / XP / 2008 / 2003 / 2000 / NT / ME / 98`